# Looking for an explanation for some lines of code

Tags: c

One section of a code looks like this:

```
char (*Words)[20] = malloc(sizeof(*Words) * 3 );
if (Words == NULL)
{
    return 1;
}

strcpy(Words[0], "Word1");
strcpy(Words[1], "Word2");
strcpy(Words[2], "Word3");
```

Can you please explain how this works? The goal of this small code is to create an array in which you can store words (and the first words are already given- Word1, Word2 and Word3).

How does this work? How does char(*Words)[20] create an array and why do we need malloc function?

Why multiply sizeof(*Words) by 3?

(Just a note, I'm aware how the last 3 lines work-- strcpy, but I dont understand the ones before them).

Answer (score 2):

```
char (*Words)[20]
```

declares `Words` to be a pointer to an array of 20 `char`s. It can also be a pointer to the beginning of an array whose elements are each an array of 20 `char`s.

`sizeof(*Words)` returns the size of that array of 20 `char`s. Multiplying by 3 gives the size of an array of 3 of those.

So this is allocating space for a 2-dimensional array. It has 3 rows, and each row is an array of 20 characters.

Then the `strcpy()` calls copy into each of those rows.

This is similar to doing

```
char **Words = malloc(3 * sizeof(char *));
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    Words[i] = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
}
```

except that it ensures that the entire 2-dimensional array is contiguous.

Your code is basically equivalent to:

```
char words[3][20] = {"Word1", "Word2", "Word3"};
```

except it uses dynamic allocation.

Comment: Just an additional question @Barmar, 
`char (*Words)[20]`

declares both an array and a pointer to it at the same time, right? If not, then how does the array get initialised?

Comment: It declares a pointer, and declares that the pointer is to an array. It gets initialized from the `malloc()` call.